# `displayManager.isDisplayCriteriaMatchingEnabled` arbitrary result (no distinction between frame rate and dynamic range)

Tags: tvos, avkit

`displayManager.isDisplayCriteriaMatchingEnabled` returns `true` if one (or both) between **refresh rate**, and **dynamic range**, is set to **match the content** in the AppleTV settings.

There's no way to make a distinction between them and check if only one of them is enabled.

Looks like Apple failed to change their APIs to me.

What am I missing?